# How to find out what launches a process on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, process, ruby

I have a bad case of a runaway process on my server. That is a Sidekiq (Ruby-based background jobs runner for a Rails based web application), it can be found as the most CPU consuming app in my `top` (technically, process name displayed as `ruby`), and its PID constantly changes, which indicates constant relaunches.

Looks like it has been attempted to run with incorrect options, due to which the process takes a lot of CPU to initialize (Sidekiq loads the whole environment of my Rails app into its memory) and then dies in an instant. Then something relaunches it again with the same incorrect options, repeating the cycle and eating away my server's performance. I need to find that something and stop it.

What I tried so far:

1. killing the process won't help, obviously - the sooner I kill it,
   the sooner it respawns
2. server reboot won't help - the rogue process is found in the `top` as soon as I can get to the server after it booting again
3. Crontab is empty
4. I thought someone attempted a `monit`
   based launch of Sidekiq, but monit configs have nothing to link them
   with the runaway process, moreover - I just wen't for removing
   `monit` altogether from the server (it was not configured and idle
   anyway). After complete removal and reboot - the rogue process is
   still there.

I need to trace now, what could respawn the process. Are there any reliable ways to find the initiating process? What other ways could be used to daemonize the process in such a way that it is being run after a server reboot and after its own crash? Any clues and tips highly appreciated.

P.S. that is my own staging server, not a production one, and I have a certain degree of freedom there (including sudo and the right to install or remove software), but I wouldn't go for lame moves like full reinstall of the OS or moving the application with a sidekiq config into different folder. I'd like to find and kill the bastard. And yes, there were a few operators on that server, no one remembers anything.

**UPDATE**: Found the rat! Catching PIDs or short living processes seemed to be an overengineering for me. I deduced that the thing that relaunches it should probably have the configs in /etc, so I did:

```
 find -H /etc -type f -exec grep -H sidekiq {} \;
```

And there was it, hiding in a file in /etc/init/. Simply deleted that file and he damn CPU eater went away that same moment.

Comment: you could trace a process's parent pid. I once wrote a script for that.

Comment: `ps hoppid {process}` does not show the 1st id of the process? That should tell you what started it. /etc/crontab and /etc/rc.*/ you checked too?